# Search and replace from txt file on many files?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have a tab separated text file that looks like this

```
1       283
28      316
128     288
```

with ~2000 lines, where the first column are numbers I want to search for and the second column what I would to replace with. This search and replace would I like to preform on ~400 text files in a directory recursively.

**Question**

Using Bash and/or Perl, what is the easiest way to do this?

**Update**

I use this for testing

```
rm -fr /tmp/a
mkdir -p /tmp/a/1/2
echo -e "1\n28\n128\n2" > /tmp/a/f.ext
echo -e "1\n28\n128\n2" > /tmp/a/1/f.ext
echo -e "1\n28\n128\n2" > /tmp/a/1/2/f.ext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **untested** solution in bash:

```
awk '{print "old="$1" new="$2}' list.txt |\
while IFS= read line; do
    declare $line
    find /path -name '*.ext' -exec sed -i "s/\b$old\b/$new/" {} +
done
```

**UNTESTED**

Comment: Oh no! please don't use `eval` like this on user input!

Comment: @JasmineLognnes you probably need to use `\b` for boundary, I've updated my answer

Comment: It was missing quotes =) Why is `IFS=` and `declare $line` needed? And what does `+` mean in the `find` command?

Comment: `declare` is not much better than `eval`. It still allows for arbitrary code execution.

Comment: So I thought, but I did a wee test; `awk '{ print "new="$1" old="$2}' <<< '1  $(whoami)' | while IFS= read line; do  declare $line; echo "$new" "$old" ; done` try replacing the `declare` by `eval`

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` it's fairly straight forward to do what you're wanting. Assuming you have a `find` version that supports `-print0`. If not… sorry, just make sure your filenames don't contain newlines.

```
#!/bin/bash

searchdir=/path/to/rescursive/search
regex=/path/to/regex/list

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r var1 var2; do # extra var is terminator
        if [[ $var1 ]]; then
            echo " ( $var1 <- $var2 ) -> $file"
            sed -i '' -E 's!'"$var1"'!'"$var2"'!g' "$file"
        fi
    done < "$regex" # input file
done < <(find "$searchdir" -name "*" -type f -print0)
```

The regex search/replace list should look like this:

```
1   283
28  316
128 288
```

Comment: Your code is horribly broken in many ways. `for file in $(find ...)`: this is pure horror. It's subject to pathname expansion and globbing. Why on earth do you need this horrible hack of saving `IFS` and restoring it? this is never done in good shell programming. You're missing the `-r` flag to `read`. You have a creative, yet wrong way to use quotes in `echo " ( "$var1" <- "$var2" ) -> "$file`. You don't need that many semicolons. This is not Java. You're betting that the variables will never contain a `!` symbol. You can only prey that it's not going to happen. Hope and prey.

Comment: You're missing quotes in your final redirection `< $REGEX`. Finally, don't use uppercase variable names in a script. And `find $SEARCHDIR` could use more quotes with `$SEARCHDIR`.

Comment: It doesn't seem broken for me; no errors at least, and does the task at hand. I realize the code is not optimal, but does one really expect a bulletproof solution in five minutes of someones spare time? Feel free to edit my answer if you think it should be better — that's what `edit` is for.

Comment: “No errors” and “does the task“ doesn't mean it's not broken. If you don't want to learn from my comment, I don't care. But then, please stop spreading your horrible methods (everything you post on this site is potentially going to be reused, and some people will try to “learn” from pieces of code shown here—you're really not doing any good).

Comment: Instead of solely criticizing here, contribute your knowledge in the form of the edit I mentioned. I do want to learn, and in this case from your example; me tinkering around with something you say is "horribly broken" isn't going to amount to anything unless I see how gniourf_gniourf does it. Work with me here, is that asking too much?

Comment: Why do you say _a comma was used in this case as the delimiter - using tab was not cooperating_?

Comment: `IFS=\t` It was mucking the file path up; probably a mistake on my part. I'm taking notes... :)

Comment: To use a tab, you have to use [ANSI-C quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting). Fixed that for you.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - I knew something was missing on that. Thank you for the advice, criticism, help, and most importantly leading by example :) Knowing the right way of doing these things is a huge plus.

Comment: `:)`. I still have a problem with your `sed` statement. For me this kind of stuff is broken. I've never found a satisfactory way to solve it. I say it's broken since if `var1` or `var2` contains a `!` then the command breaks. It's possible to escape it, but it's not really nice. It's possible to discard lines that contain `!` altogether…

Comment: And also, if `var1=1`, then all the `1`'s in file will be replaced by the expansion of `var2`. Not good.

Comment: From my understanding any delimiter can be used with `sed`, so rather than using `!`, the character `@` could be used instead for example.

Comment: Sure, any character can be chosen, but any character can also potentially appear in the variables `:)`.

Comment: Indeed; is there a standard means of dealing with such situations? Surely it's not the "hope and prey" method :D.

Comment: I don't know of any comfortable method to deal with that, using `sed`, unfortunately. There are too many things to control: separator and all the possible regex characters. That's too much for me to control.

Comment: I still have 2 problems with this: first one (already mentioned) is that if `var1` is `1`, then all the `1`'s in the file will be replaced. Second problem is that replacement will be recursive: if `regex` file contains the lines `1 2` and `2 3` then all the `1`'s and all the `2`'s will be replaced by `3`'s. I'm not sure OP wants this behavior.

Comment: That sed line is quite hideous, putting it lightly. I'm wondering if `awk` is a better solution there, unless there's unforeseen circumstances in that regard as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # START -- how-to search and replace recursively in file paths and contents
    export dir=/var/some/dir; 
    export to_srch="foo"
    export to_repl="bar"

    # those are bonus oneliners - skip them if you do not want to change
    # file paths
    #-- search and replace in file names, skip those in .git ( 
    find "$dir/"  -not -path "./.git/*" -type d |\
    perl -nle '$o=$_;s#'"$to_srch"'#'"$to_repl"'#g;$n=$_;`mkdir -p $n` ;'
    find "$dir/"  -not -path "./.git/*" -type f -name '*.txt' |\
    perl -nle '$o=$_;s#'"$to_srch"'#'"$to_repl"'#g;$n=$_;rename($o,$n) unless -e $n ;'


    #-- search and replace in file contents, skip those in .git
    find "$dir/" -not -path "./.git/*" -type f -name '*.txt' -exec \
    perl -pi -e "s#$to_srch#$to_repl#g" {} \;
    find "$dir/" -not -path "./.git/*" -type f -name '*.bak' | xargs rm -f"
    # STOP  -- how-to rename files recursively in file paths and contents
```